# Confluence migration to another Confluence

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api

I need to migrate some wiki content from one Confluence to another, hosted in a different server. I need help towards using the API (export is not an option, as it seems to be broken in our instance) How to extract all the content? How to save all that content to the target server?

PS: I also tried through WebDev, however it only produces blank pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can sue the following appraoches to migrate the data:

1. Use standard export space feature (xHTML/XML data) and import it to another instance
2. Use REST API to to get data from space/pages/page of one Confluence (pages / labels / attachments, etc.) and also use REST API to create new pages in another Confluence (https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/confluence/rest/v1/)
3. If both are Confluence Server, you can use Java API (https://developer.atlassian.com/server/crowd/) to get data from space/pages/page and save as you need (HTML, wiki, text, etc.) and create content from this data in another Confluence